# Setting the Group Bypass property of a Node

Tags: origen-sdk

I can't seem to find an answer from the documentation http://origen-sdk.org/origen/guides/program/flowapi/

From SmartTest 7.1.3 and later of Advantest, we have the option to set “Group Bypass” property of the Group node testflow component.

```
{
  run_and_branch(TestA)
  then
  {
  }
  else
  {
    if @Alarm then
    {
      binout;
    }
    else
    {
    }
  }
  run_and_branch(TestB)
  then
  {
  }
  else
  {
    if @Alarm then
    {
      binout;
    }
    else
    {
    }
  }
}, groupbypass, open,"DataCollectionTests", ""
```

I tried using if_flag:, continue: and if_enable properties in my group definition but I’m getting an

```
if @GROUPBYPASS == 1 then
{
  .
  .
  .
}, open,"DataCollectionTests", ""
```

in the flow instead. 
What is the correct way of hooking up into this property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This property is not currently supported, if you want it added please open a ticket describing it here: https://github.com/Origen-SDK/origen_testers/issues

In the meantime, you could generate it by using the `render` method which allows you to explicitly define code to be injected into the flow.

For example:

```ruby
render '{'

# Your existing code to be wrapped in the group here, e.g.
test :testA

render '}, groupbypass, open,"DataCollectionTests", ""'
```

You could create your own helper method for that within your interface:

```ruby
def group_bypass(name)
  render '{'
  yield
  render "}, groupbypass, open,\"#{name}\", \"\""
end
```

Then in your flow:

```ruby
group_bypass "DataCollectionTests" do

  # Your existing code to be wrapped in the group here, e.g.
  test :testA

end
```

Comment: Thanks! I have raised the request here https://github.com/Origen-SDK/origen_testers/issues/87 and marked the answer as correct.